# « Cela dit » versus « Ceci dit »

Tags: usage, pronoms, démonstratifs

Il m'arrive assez souvent d'entendre ces formules en réunion lorsqu'un locuteur s'exprime.

Par ailleurs, il semblerait que le pronom démonstratif *ceci* annonce ce qui va être dit rendant incongru et anachronique « ceci dit ».

N'étant pas de langue maternelle française, j'aimerais qu'on éclaire ma lanterne sur le sujet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est parfois un tic verbal, une sorte de pose dans la réflexion ou une façon d'insister qui n'apporte souvent pas grand chose à la démonstration.
Lorsque cela devient systématique, on ne peut s'empêcher de penser « Mais qu'est-ce qu'il lui veut à ce *Sidi* ».

*Cela étant dit*, je peux changer complètement d'hypothèse ; ce qui est au départ le sens d'une des deux formules.

Pour différencier le bon usage, il faut transposer à l'écrit : si l'on peut écrire « Cela posé *(ou ceci selon la proximité de la cible référencée)*, nous pouvons poursuivre notre discours dans une direction plus approfondie *(ou complètement différente)* », la formule est justifiée, sinon il est préférable de ne pas l'utiliser.

Answer (score 2):

Pour moi, « ceci dit » est très courant pour dire « pour parler d'autre chose » (« maintenant » peut aussi être utilisé comme ça). *Ceci* désigne alors ce qui vient d'être dit : « maintenant que ça a été dit, on peut passer à autre chose ».

Je ne vois pas vraiment de raison pour désigner ça avec *cela* plutôt que *ceci*, donc la formule me semble correcte. La cible est proche, de toutes façons.

Comment: Ça me semble très subjectif. J'ai pour ma part tendance à facilement utiliser « cela dit », parfois à outrance (plusieurs fois par jour sur FL&U), et presque jamais « ceci dit ». Pour les raisons données par l'OP, la formulation qui utilise le pronom *ceci* me choque un tantinet.

Comment: Mon explication est subjective, ou l'appréciation de ceci plutôt que cela (et visse vers ça) est subjective ?

Comment: Le choix entre « ceci dit » et « cela dit ».